# Why does functional testing create new records on my Redis query cache?

Tags: caching, redis, symfony

I've just enabled query caching on my symfony application using the following configuration:

**Doctine cache config**

```
doctrine_cache:
    providers:
        cache:
            namespace: '%cache_namespace%'
            chain:
                providers:
                    - array_cache
                    - redis_cache
                    - file_cache
        redis_cache:
            namespace: '%cache_namespace%'
            predis:
                host: "%redis_host%"
                port: "%redis_port%"
                password: "%redis_password%"
                timeout: "%redis_timeout%"
        array_cache:
            namespace: '%cache_namespace%'
            array: ~
        file_cache:
            namespace: '%cache_namespace%'
            file_system:
                directory: "%kernel.cache_dir%/application"
```

**Doctrine ORM config**

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    entity_managers:
        an_entity_manager:
            connection: connection
            mappings:
                AppBundle: ~
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            metadata_cache_driver:
                type: service
                id: "doctrine_cache.providers.cache"
            query_cache_driver:
                type: service
                id: "doctrine_cache.providers.cache"
            result_cache_driver:
                type: service
                id: "doctrine_cache.providers.cache"
```

I'm also having functional tests that populate a local sqlite database instead of the real one. What I'm seeing is the following:

Every time I run my tests, I see the Redis cache creating new keys even for identical records. I'm guessing this must be because the database gets re-created before every test gets executed, and the contents of the newly created rows don't matter as far as caching is concerned, but I can't be sure.

Does anyone know if this expected behaviour?

Comment: Your question looks a bit confusing because you're not doing unit-tests here. In a real unit-test you would mock away your connection because you're not testing that but your smallest possible testable unit.

Comment: You are right, I actually meant functional tests. Will edit the question

Answer (score 0):

You should disable Redis (and all unecessary external dependencies) in you test environment. This could be done overriding your configuration in the test env, using the in-memory cache only.

To read more abound environments and configuration, you can look into the Symfony docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/configuration.html#environment-configuration

Comment: Possibly a good idea, but it does not answer my question. Just mentioning to avoid possible similar answers from other users